# Match urls with trailing slash

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello in a project we have the following code to search for urls & emails and replace them with links. This work great but it doesn't match urls like

> https://www.example.com/

which have a trailing slash.

```
API.prototype.replaceURLS = function(str) {

    var patterns = [
        "\\b((?:https?|ftp)://[^\\s\"'<>]?/+)\\b",
        "\\b(www\\.[^\\s\"'<>]?/+)\\b",
        "\\b(\\w[\\w.+-]*@[\\w.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,6})\\b"
    ];

    var reg = new RegExp(patterns.join('|'), "gi");

    return str.replace(reg, function(match, url, www, mail) {

        if (url) {
            return "<a target='_blank' href=\"" + url + "\">" + url + "</a>";
        }

        if (www) {
            return "<a target='_blank' href=\"http://" + www + "\">" + www + "</a>";
        }

        if (mail) {
            return "<a href=\"mailto:" + mail + "\">" + mail + "</a>";
        }

        // just in case...
        return match;

    });

};
```

Regex:

```
\b((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^\s"'<>]+)\b|\b(www\.[^\s"'<>]+)\b|\b(\w[\w.+-]*@[\w.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6})\b
```

Comment: It doesn't even seem to handle `https://www.example.com` correctly?

Comment: It does you can try at https://regex101.com/

Comment: It doesn't match - https://regex101.com/r/RrMTXz/1 . And that's (partly) because your regex'es are faulty. Your `url` and `www` regex'es both have `[^\\s\"'<>]?/+` which matches one character that isn't space, quote, `<` or `>`, followed by one or more `/`. I'm guessing that's not what you want.

Comment: @ClassG hm, yeah the regex in the code is different than the regex posted after the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up removing all `\b` flags and works fine